# Converting pandas to multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, pickle

I have a pandas dataset that looks like this:

```
check_d = pickle.load(a_file)
```

[image]

when I type:

```
check_d["conv2"]
```

I get:

```
n00005787_9986.JPEG     [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0....
n00006484_9999.JPEG     [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 9.846705, -0.0, -0.0,...
n00007846_99456.JPEG    [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0....
n00015388_9991.JPEG     [-0.0, 9.055762, -0.0, 3.3329132, -0.0, -0.0, ...
n00017222_9935.JPEG     [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 13.863088, -0.0...
                                              ...                        
n15093298_9.JPEG        [-0.0, -0.0, 29.058922, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0...
n15102359_129.JPEG      [-0.0, -0.0, 17.293856, -0.0, -0.0, 201.57753,...
n15102455_9991.JPEG     [-0.0, 64.55209, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0,...
n15102894_997.JPEG      [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 73.35719, 5.8023753, -0.0, ...
n00004475_6590.JPEG     [-0.0, 33.83642, -0.0, 62.97699, 8.908251, -0....
Name: conv2, Length: 19892, dtype: object
```

and `type(check_d["conv2"])` is `pandas.core.series.Series`

I want to convert this to 4 dictionaries: "conv2", "conv4", "fc6" and "fc8".

So in each dictionary, keys are `n*****_****.JPEG`, and values are the corresponding value from the pandas file. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide a **small** but **reproducible** example and the **complete** expected output. With so many `...` it's hard to know what you really want and just risks to waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your task with a simple example, which includes your core aspects.

1. Convert each column / Series into its own dictionary
2. Each dictionary should include the index entries as keys and the corresponding values as values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
                       b=[['a', 'b', 'c'],
                          ['d', 'e', 'f'],
                          ['g', 'h', 'i']]
                       ),
                  index=['first', 'second', 'third']
                  )

print(df)
                a          b
first   [1, 2, 3]  [a, b, c]
second  [4, 5, 6]  [d, e, f]
third   [7, 8, 9]  [g, h, i]
```

```
list_of_dicts = []
for col in df.columns:
    col_dict = {key: values for
                key, values in df[col].items()
                }
    list_of_dicts.append((col, col_dict))

print(list_of_dicts)
[('a', {'first': [1, 2, 3], 'second': [4, 5, 6], 'third': [7, 8, 9]}), ('b', {'first': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'second': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'third': ['g', 'h', 'i']})]
```

As I wanted to avoid to hardcode the dictionary names as in your example to make this scalable for any quantity of columns, I did not directly create the target dictionary with desired names, but instead return a list of tuples, where the first item of the tuple represents the column name / your desired dictionary name and the second item represents the dictionary itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is simply the `to_dict()` method of `pandas.DataFrame` as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict).

For example, here is some code to create a DataFrame similar to yours:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'conv2': [
            np.array([-0.0, -0.0, -0.0]),
            np.array([-0.0, -0.0, -0.0]),
            np.array([-0.0, -0.0, -0.0])
        ],
        'conv4' : [
            np.array([32.3, 13.5, -0.0]),
            np.array([8.08, 10.2, -0.0]),
            np.array([18.59, -0.0, -0.0])
        ],
    },
    index=['n001.jpg', 'n002.jpg', 'n003.jpg']
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                       conv2                conv4
n001.jpg  [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0]   [32.3, 13.5, -0.0]
n002.jpg  [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0]   [8.08, 10.2, -0.0]
n003.jpg  [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0]  [18.59, -0.0, -0.0]
```

Then simply call `to_dict()` to get dictionaries (using pprint in this example to pretty-print the output):

```py
from pprint import pprint
pprint(df.to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'conv2': {'n001.jpg': array([-0., -0., -0.]),
           'n002.jpg': array([-0., -0., -0.]),
           'n003.jpg': array([-0., -0., -0.])},
 'conv4': {'n001.jpg': array([32.3, 13.5, -0. ]),
           'n002.jpg': array([ 8.08, 10.2 , -0.  ]),
           'n003.jpg': array([18.59, -0.  , -0.  ])}}
```

If so desired, you could also try some of the other `to_dict()` output formats defined by specifying a value for the `orient` keyword: e.g. `df.to_dict(orient="index")`